# How to allow comma in bootstrap tags input filter?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using below code to submit tags using bootstrap tags input filter, I want to allow **comma** in tags. Please help.

```
$('.tagsinput').tagsinput({
        maxTags: 15,
        trimValue: true,
        confirmKeys: [13],
        allowDuplicates: false,
        onTagExists: function(item, $tag) {
            alert('Tag already exists')
            $tag.hide.fadeIn();
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Edit

Since the time of the original writing [it looks like two options now exist for this](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/blob/master/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.js#L94): `delimiter` and `delimiterRegex`. So you should be able to do `.tagsinput({ delimiter: '|' })` or `.tagsinput({ delimiterRegex: /\s+/ })`. [The default is still `,`](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/blob/master/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.js#L23).

### Original post

There is no option for that, so you'd have to change the code for the plugin. [Line 87 of bootstrap-tagsinput.js](https://github.com/timschlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput/blob/master/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.js#L87) splits on the `,` character. You could change that to be a different character, like `;` or `|`. If you wanted to make it more extensible you could add `splitOn: ','` to `defaultOptions`, then and change line 87 to be `var items = item.split(self.options.splitOn);`. You can add `self.options.splitOn &&` to the `if` statement above too, which will keep it from trying to split when there's nothing to split on.

So, the code changes will need to look like this:

```js
// Line 4
var defaultOptions = {
    splitOn: ','
    // ...
};

// Line 86
if (self.options.splitOn && typeof item === "string" && this.$element[0].tagName === 'INPUT') {
  var items = item.split(self.options.splitOn);
  // ...
}
```

You'll want to keep using `confirmKeys: [ 13 ]`, and you'll probably want to use a `<select multiple></select>` instead of an `<input />` so that you get an array instead of a comma separated string when you do `$(".tagsinput").val();`

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/35efe0fy/2/).

Comment: splitOn is not available in current js file.

Comment: Just as a clarification for the current version, you have to set: {..., confirmKeys: [13], delimiter: '|', ...}

Answer (score 0):

Add your tags as objects instead of strings, e.g.:

```
el.tagsinput({
  itemValue: 'value',
  itemText: 'text',
  maxTags: 15,
  trimValue: false,
  //...
});

el.tagsinput('add', { "value": 1 , "text": "Tag 1," });
el.tagsinput('add', { "value": 2 , "text": "Tag 2," });
//...
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if you're programmatically adding tags? What about having a user type something?